# Probability of getting 4 diferent prizes with 7 trys

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 4 different prices, one of the has a probability of 1/8 while the other 3 divide evenly the rest of the probability.

I get 7 tries, what is the probability of getting one of each.

What i thought was multiplying the probabilities if i had only 4 tries then multiplying that probability for C(7,4), but they tell me im wrong, any help?

Comment: Well, your reasoning would be wrong already in case you have two draws with 100% chance each. You'd get a probability of 200%.

Comment: Can you compute the probability of the compliment? What is the probability that after 7 tries you only have 3 or fewer different prizes?

Answer (score 1):

You have four prizes with the probability of getting the first on one trial being $p=1/8$, and the probability of getting a particular one of the others being each $q=7/24$.

Let $A^c,B^c,C^c,D^c$ be the events of *not* getting each of the prizes in the seven tries.

Use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to evaluate $1-P(A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c\cup D^c)$

> $\begin{align}P(A^c) & = (1-p)^7 = (3q)^7\\ P(B^c)=P(C^c)=P(D^c) & = (1-q)^7\\ P(A^c, B^c)=P(A^c,C^c)=P(A^c,D^c) & = (1-p-q)^7= (2q)^7\\ P(B^c,C^c)=P(B^c,D^c)=P(C^c,D^c) & = (1-2q)^7 \\ P(A^c,B^c,C^c)=P(A^c,B^c,D^c)=P(A^c,C^c,D^c) & =(1-p-2q)^7 = q^7\\P(B^c,C^c,D^c) & =(1-3q)^7 = p^7 \\ P(A^c,B^c,C^c,D^c) & = 0\end{align}$